# Can not access global variables inside a jQuery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I am  using the following code to track the scrolling and I want to put the selected element variables outside the event handler so they are not called each time the user scrolls thereby saving resources. The following only works if I put the first two variables inside the event handler:

```
    var recommend_con_list=$(".recommend_con_list")
    var recommend_con=$('.recommend_con')
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var y=$(window).scrollTop()
        if(y > 82){
            recommend_con.css({position:"fixed",top:"0"})
        }else{
            recommend_con.css({position:"",top:""})
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is this code executed inside of the `document` `ready` handler? Or after the `.recommend_con_list` and `.recomment_con` elements are available/rendered? Otherwise, the selectors won't work because the elements won't be found, and the variables will hold no elements

Comment: No they are not inside `documnet``ready` handler. I will try now it with `ready`.

Comment: Thank you it works now. Although it does not make a lot of difference.It still consumes up to 20% of the CPU.

Comment: Show your actual code. At some point, you can't optimize it anymore (unless you want to stop using jQuery objects/methods) which may not be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to optimize further, I would use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var recommend_con_list = $(".recommend_con_list").get(),
        recommend_con = $('.recommend_con').get(),
        $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function () {
        var y = $window.scrollTop();
        if (y > 82) {
            for (var i = 0, j = recommend_con.length; i < j; i++) {
                recommend_con[i].classList.add("special");
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0, j = recommend_con.length; i < j; i++) {
                recommend_con[i].classList.remove("special");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

With this CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .special {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: What I am doing is something different. I am trying to make a vertical list scrolls slowly than the rest of the page element like this `recommend_con_list.parent().css({marginTop:(82-y)/3+"px"})` it is placed within `recommend_con` which will be fixed in place and has hidden overflow. My question is already answered but I will accept your answer as you used a variable for `$(window)` and I think it helps. Another thing, the newest Firefox has a very smooth scrolling and with this code CPU consumption increases significantly unlike chrome.